# Image urls change while scraping in Node (works in browser console)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm using [artoo.js](https://github.com/medialab/artoo/) for web scraping however For some reason the scraped image url's change when working with cheerio in node . i.e the original image url is :

`"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWU4NmY3MTMtMTBmMi00NjFjLTkwMmItYWZhZWUwNDg5M2ExXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"`

However after scraping the Url turns to this url:

`"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/156x231/tv-3797070466._CB522736147_.png@._V1_SX300.jpg"`

If I scrape it while in chrome browser console using Artoo.js bookmark. The Url stays same as original.
Why is it changing when i use it in node?.Any Suggestions

UPDATE: Update: I think I found the issue but not the solution. It seems the scraper method runs before the correct images have loaded on page. the changed URL is just the placeholder image. How can I wait till the entire page loads.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by some JS code. If you are using `request`+`cheerio` to scrap the page. When you make the request in node the JS code does nothing (it's not interpreted). So you are probably getting the original url before any lib or piece of code changes it. Try to look at the source code of the page in the browser `Crtl+u`. If it's `"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/156x231/tv-3797070466._CB522736147_.png@._V1_SX300.jpg"` then you will know some piece of code is doing something to change it.

### Edit

If you absolutly need to run the JS to obtain the URL. You sould use `phantomjs`. It's a headless browser. The imaes will load. You can use it directly from `nodejs` or if you want a simpler way go with `casperjs`. I assume you're not used to scraping complicated web apps. If it's the case would go with casperjs. It's easy and it does the job. It's not as fast as using `request` + `cheerio` but it works. And you can put your code to run on a server.

Comment: I think it may be because the images have not loaded on page. I may need to figure out to delay the scraping

Comment: They won't load if you're just making a request in node

Comment: If you're using the `request` module. You will only get the source code of the page. It will not load external resources.

Comment: is scraping from inside the chrome console the only option?

Comment: Do you have more examples? We could try to find a way to generate the true url using the source code. The end of the URL's is identical. If we can identify a patern we can replace the begining of the url to get the real one.

Comment: @jasan Did you find any solution to the above problem you reported , as i am also looking for some solution.